# Gradle: custom message on task failure?

Tags: gradle

I'd like to hook into the compileJava target and spit out an additional custom message on failure. We've got a really common case setup case that a lot of folks overlook and it'd be useful, only on failure, to be able to do something like:

```
compileJava.onFailure { 
   println "Did you configure your wampfrankle to talk to the slackometer?" 
}
```

My Google skills have not yet led to an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is a dependency error and as Rene points out that needs to be detected after the build has executed, not after the project has been evaluated.

Here I've added a call to buildFinished with a closure that detects if a failure has happened and prints out an error message.

```
project.gradle.buildFinished { buildResult ->
  if (buildResult.getFailure() != null) {
    println "Did you configure your wampfrankle to talk to the slackometer?" 
  }
}
```

To test this I force a dependency resolution failure with this bogus dependency:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'foo:bar:baz'
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the failure is "null" in this case. The failure is actually a failure to resolve a dependency, so maybe that's why. However, I haven't figured out how to hook into dependency resolution success/failure.

Comment: afterProject is not triggered after a project is built. you might want to check project.gradle.buildFinished . This hook is called when a build has finished and you can check the tasks for it's state to gather additional information

Comment: Ah I see.  You can put up and answer or I will correct this answer after testing it out.

Comment: Very close. The buildFinished is getting called many times for the failing "compileJava" task and I'm not sure why. Maybe for each transitive dependency?

Comment: Ah, figured out buildFinished() is called for every subproject, even if I'm only building one of the subprojects. At least, I think that's the reason as the number of invocations matches up even if there's nothing in the BuildResult object indicating what project it was for.

Answer (score 5):

Use `finalizedBy` on a task that executes `onlyIf` the first task fails. For example:

```
tasks.compileJava.finalizedBy('compileJavaOnFailure')

task compileJavaOnFailure {
  doLast {
    println 'Did you configure your wampfrankle to talk to the slackometer?'
  }

  onlyIf {
    tasks.compileJava.state.failure != null
  }
}
```